# FPDF: Add some text at the END of the page

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I want to add some text like, "Prepared by," on the last page of the PDF. In my case, I display 2 rows of data in the first page and 3 rows of data for second page onwards.

The problem that I faced is if the last page got 1 or 2 rows data only, the "Prepared by" will show on the same page. But, if the last page got 3 rows of data, the "Prepared by" will show at the next page which is a blank page (no rows of data). Below is my code:

```
      $count = 0;
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user3)){
        //rendering row.....
        //.....

          if ((($count - 4) % 3) === 0) {

            $pdf->AddPage();

          }

        $count++;
      }

      $pdf->Cell(0,5,'',0,1,"C");
      $pdf->Cell(63,8,'Prepared by,',0,0,"C");

  $pdf->Output();
```

Can anyone know what is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add this .

```
      $count = 0;
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user3)){
        //rendering row.....
        //.....

          if ((($count - 4) % 3) === 0) {

            $pdf->AddPage();

          }

        $count++;
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Prepared by: Your Name');
}
}
  $pdf->Output();
```

Comment: @incongnitorecon i get the error this: Cannot redeclare Footer() (previously declared in

Comment: @RadamelFalcao can you provide full codes as i am not sure where do you put your footer

Comment: Can you ivt me in chat?